# Считывание данных из файла в структуру

Tags: c

Есть структура

```
typedef struct BitMapFileHeader
{
    WORD bfType; // Тип файла (должен быть BM).
    DWORD bfSize; // Размер файла в байтах.
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2; // Зарезервированные поля.
    DWORD bfOffBits; // Смещение битового массива относительно начала файла.
} BMF;
```

Есть ли возможность заполнить значения элементов структуры, считывая данные из файла, то есть первые 2 байта - первый элемент, следующие 4 байта - следующий элемент. Спасибо!

Comment: Именно побайтово? Конечно можно. А можно и сразу всю структуру сразу...

Comment: @Harry А как это реализуется?

Comment: См. функцию `fread`. Файл следует открывать в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое!